# SpaCy Lemmatizer working differently for a direct string and tokenized string

Tags: tokenize, spacy, lemmatization

I have two sentences one which is send to lemmatizer with a full string. The other is sent in tokenized version to the following functions.

```
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

    def lemmatize(text: str):
        

        doc = nlp(text.lower())
        lemmas = []

        for token in doc:
            lemmas.append(token.lemma_)

        return lemmas
    
    def tokenize(text: str):

        doc = nlp(text.lower())
        tokens = [token.text for token in doc if not token.is_punct]
        return tokens
```

So, when I run the following code,

```
text  = "Testing and Coding"
tokens = lemmatize(text)  
print(tokens)
```

It returns

```
>>> ['testing', 'and', 'code']
```

But when I run the following code,

```
tokens = tokenize(text) 

tokens = [lemmatize(token)[0] for token in tokens]
print(tokens)
```

It returns

```
>>> ['test', 'and', 'code']
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Can anyone explain?

Thanks!

Comment: can specify the version of spacy you are using

Comment: Lemmatization relies on the part-of-speech and the parser is guessing differently if you only pass in one token vs the sentence.  Try printing out the token.pos_.  In the first case it thinks "Testing" is a NOUN, the lemma of which is "testing".  In the second it thinks you have a VERB, the lemma of which is "test".

Comment: @bivouac0 Thank you. That is the problem.

Comment: @AnuragWagh I am using spacy 2.3.2